Migrate from SAP Crystal Reports to an alternative in .NET project
As there will never be a SAP Crystal Reports library for modern .NET, in a project I'm working for compatibility had to create a wrapper .NET Framework console app to generate CR reports. What could be an alternative to SAP CR that could create reports from SqlServer and Oracle databases, comaptible with modern .NET, export to PDF and would have a report designer, preferably not pricey?

The most expensive part of the project will be the migration (development) of the reports to the new reporting engine, since you need to spend time to develop and test each report. There will be a learning curve too. The application is one time development, but will still be relatively expensive because you need to implement a level of abstraction in order to be able to work with different reports. For reporting engine you can use DevExperss reports or Active reports and they both are in the neighborhood of $1000-$1500. As I said , this will be the smallest expense, since you are going to spend much more on development. My guess is that you have an app which is using .NET Framework to run Crystal reports.  Why do you care about what framework is used by the application ?

still having a separate.net framework app brings deployment, maintenance issues so having all in one solution like it was before looks more sustainable in the long run. also questions about SAP CR engine support arise, how long it will be supported, anyway this looks like a problem that needs to be solved eventually.
